# Add custom rule between ionic <ion-item>

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I am trying to put a custom horizontal rule between the `<ion-item>`s in my list.

My CSS works fine with `<ion-list>` except that `<ion-list>` adds its own rules which I don't want. I just want my custom rule.

If I try using `<ion-list no-lines>` (to remove the rules that `<ion-list>` adds automatically my CSS doesn't work any more, and I don't get my custom rules.

My CSS is:

```
.my-item {
  border-style:solid;
  border-bottom-width: 11px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="my-item>Something</ion-item>
  <ion-item class="my-item>Something Else</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**ADDED MY REAL CODE**

In case this helps here is the actual code I am using:

```css
page-my-plans {

    }

    .pu-my-plans-plus-circle {
      display: block;
      //border: 2px solid white;
      background-color: $pu-orange;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 38px;
      width: 38px;
    }

    .pu-my-plans-plus-circle span {
      font-size: 38px;
      font-weight: 100;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: -7px;
      left: 8.5px;
    }
    .pu-plan-addButton {
      font-size: 30px;
      margin-right: 14px;
      margin-top:-2px;
    }


    .pu-section-list-item{
      color: black;
      font-weight:$pu-item-font-weight;
      font-size:$pu-item-font-size;
      padding-left:20px;
      padding-right:0px;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
    .item{
      background: transparent !important;
    }


    // THEMING CSS
    // ===========
    //
    .pu-my-plans-background {
      background-image: url("../assets/img/PU_Light_BG_1.png");
      background-size: cover !important;
    }
    .pu-my-plans-item {
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 11px solid black;
    }
    .pu-my-plans-plan-date {
      color: black; //$pu-orange;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
```

```html
<ion-content class="pu-my-plans-background">

  <div *ngIf="hasPlans">
    <ion-list no-lines class="pu-item-list">
      <!--<ion-item-group reorder="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)">-->
        <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let plan of plans; let i = index" >
          <ion-item class="pu-section-list-item pu-my-plans-item" (click)="editPlan(plan.id, plan.rev, plan.title, i)">
            {{ plan.title }}
            <br>
            <span class="pu-my-plans-plan-date">{{ plan.updated}}</span>
            <button *ngIf="plan.important" ion-button clear item-right>
              <ion-icon name="ios-alert-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item-options side="right">
            <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deletePlan(plan.id, plan.rev)">
              <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>
              Delete
            </button>
          </ion-item-options>
          <div class="xxx">SOME TEXT</div>
        </ion-item-sliding>
      <!--</ion-item-group>-->
    </ion-list>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

With this code my attempts to get a border rule fail. If I add `no-lines` to `<ion-list>` my border works but I also get the lines that `<ion-list>` produces.

This is what it looks like with the code above:

[image]

If I take away `no-rules` it looks like this:

[image]

There is a rule at the bottom of the list and the last item does not have the border I am trying to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just preface your own border with a reset.

```
.my-item {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 11px solid black;
}
```

**Edit:**

Ionic 2's ios styles also contain a rule, specific to the last child and it's border, which is what needs to be overridden here.

```
.list-ios>.item-block:last-child, .list-ios>.item-wrapper:last-child .item-block { 
    border-bottom: .55px solid #c8c7cc; 
}
```

Comment: I still get thin unwanted lines from ion-list. Also my border-bottom does not apply the the last ion-item

Comment: You can step up specificity to override any other rules. Is you code live anywhere I can take a look?

Comment: No sorry it isn;t live anywhere (I have never worked out how to get an ionic project on plunker). What do you mean by 'step up specificity'?

Comment: In css you can increase specificity by adding more selectors to your style rule. For example, I used .my-item but you can make it more specific with something like .list .item.my-item but it depends a little bit on your generated html structure.

Comment: I have tried various combinations of adding selectors such as item, list-item, item-selector, etc.

Comment: Try to include generated html into your original question and maybe an image of the current state. I can't do much else without seeing more details.

Comment: I have added the real code I am using to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134200/discussion-between-serg-chernata-and-bill-noble).

Answer (score 0):

I can help you, but i need to acces source code. http://view.ionic.io/